# Django mysqlclient install

Tags: mysql, django, database, python-3.x, installation

I am trying to start learning Django, but I can't even pass through the installation. I have Python 3.4, Django, setuptools and Apache installed. Is database all that is left to setup?

Also, I wanted to try with MySQL and this is the link from djangoproject: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysqlclient

The problem is that I can't find any information on what .whl file should I download, how to open it and if that is all I have to do. I dont get why there isn't some integrated Django developement kit or something, but that is a question for some other forum :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'd recommend that you read up the basics of `virtualenv` (http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) and continue from there.

Basically following commands should get you running:

```
$ cd ~/your_project_directory
$ virtualenv env
$ source env/bin/activate
$ pip install django
$ pip install mysql-python
```

Make sure you have MySQL (server) installed on your system. If you're on Mac OS X, `brew` (http://brew.sh/) is quite handy.

Comment: So, when I'm in the virtual environment, i install the software package that I need with "pip install <name>" similarly to debian's "sudo apt-get <name>"?

Comment: Let's take this example: "Project A" requires Django==1.4.1 and "Project B" requires Django==1.6.7. If you install the packages system wide with pip (yes, like "apt-get"), this could mess up one setup. Virtualenv helps to you to separate the dependencies.

Comment: i hate to bother any further, but the command 'source env/bin/activate' didn't work. However, inside the project directory's env folder, I found 'activate' inside Scripts directory. I presume that the 'cd env -> cd scripts -> activate' command sequence will do the trick?

Comment: Are you on a windows machine? Then yes, scripts directory. Again, I'd recommend to read the documentation (e.g. https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide.html)

Comment: I did read it, though not thoroughly because of deadlines. It works like a charm. I know I shouldn't be going around thanking people here, but you provided valuable help. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 30):

You don't download the whl file yourself. You use pip to install it directly:

```
pip install mysqlclient.
```

Note that you *don't* need this to try Django; nor do you need Apache. Python and Django is already an "integrated development environment" since Python includes sqlite3, and Django includes a development server.

Comment: Ah excelent. apt-get autoremove seems to have removed this!

Comment: You need this to have Django working with DB.

Comment: You can not install mysqlclient like this, it will just throw error on most OS

Answer (score 11):

Here is my solution. Make sure your virtualenv is activated, then type the following:

```
apt-get install default-libmysqlclient-dev
pip install mysqlclient
```

Comment: hi @tuke-tv, i am getting this error


    E: Unable to locate package default-libmysqlclient-dev

Comment: @sanjay Just go for here: https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to download any whl file

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

will work just fine .
In case you get any Microsoft Visual C++ error try

```
 pip install --only-binary :all: mysqlclient﻿
```

hope it helps .

Answer (score 1):

```
brew install mysql-connector-c
brew install mysql
brew unlink mysql-connector-c
sudo pip install pymysql
sudo pip install mysqlclient
```

Try running these commands on the terminal to install mysqlclient

Answer (score 0):

[easy to miss the 64-bit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIgDL.png)

You might got the wrong bit version of Python. Check that your bit version of python is correct. I by misstake downloaded the 32-bit version of Python and I got the same issue as you. I could do `pip install mysqlclient` with the 64-bit version without any issues.

(note that the windowsx86 on the image is 32-bit)

Answer (score 0):

I solved through these steps:

pip install --upgrade pip

pip install --upgrade setuptools

pip install mysqlclient==1.4.6

if mysqlclient==1.4.6 will not work then try some other versions

pip install mysqlclient==x.x.x