# MySQL-python installation not working within virtualenv

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-3.6

I am trying to connect a MySQL database to my Django project, but when I try to install MySQL-python, it gives me the following error:

```
Collecting mysql-python
  Using cached MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/fr/3k1nrq490dzdz9s48k49m9640000gn/T/pip-build-4dsuxwwv/mysql-python/setup.py", line 13, in <module>
        from setup_posix import get_config
      File "/private/var/folders/fr/3k1nrq490dzdz9s48k49m9640000gn/T/pip-build-4dsuxwwv/mysql-python/setup_posix.py", line 2, in <module>
        from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/fr/3k1nrq490dzdz9s48k49m9640000gn/T/pip-build-4dsuxwwv/mysql-python/
```

I have tried `pip3 install ConfigParser`, but while it gets installed, the error still occurs.

When I try to run my Django server, it prints out a long error log, and at the end:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.
Did you install mysqlclient?
```

and when I looked at the following link, it said that I should install MySQL-python: [Django mysqlclient install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30015983/django-mysqlclient-install)

May seem like a newbie question, but I can't seem to find similar errors elsewhere online.

EDIT:: Ok, looks like MySQL-python is not for python-3.6

While I did `pip3 install mysqlclient`, the virtualenv is saying that I have already installed it when I run the command again. But when I try to `python3 manage.py runserver`, I get the above error, asking if I had installed it. When I try to give an answer, I am unable to. Everytime I press ENTER, it just creates a new line and the prompt is still active.

The above error is preceded by the following text:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x1059d9048>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/karthikpullela/Desktop/Django-projects/QB-test/QB/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 15, in <module>
    import MySQLdb as Database
  File "/Users/karthikpullela/Desktop/Django-projects/QB-test/QB/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    import _mysql
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/karthikpullela/Desktop/Django-projects/QB-test/QB/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_mysql.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/karthikpullela/Desktop/Django-projects/QB-test/QB/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_mysql.cpython-36m-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
```

Comment: Possibly duplicated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14087598/python-3-importerror-no-module-named-configparser

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 3 ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14087598/python-3-importerror-no-module-named-configparser)

Comment: Got it, thanks for the heads up. But, whenever I try to run python3 manage.py runserver, I get the following error, and when I try to answer, I am unable to: 
    django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.
    Did you install mysqlclient?

Comment: That's the result of unsuccessfully installation of MySQL-python. Once you can install it, the later error message will disappear.

Comment: What if you used the recommend driver instead? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/databases/#mysql-db-api-drivers

Comment: Here's the thing. According to the other stackoverflow link, MySQL-python does not work for python3, and I am using python3. Apparently I need mysqlclient, which, while I have it already installed, is not working.

Comment: It's possible that you installed it into the wrong environment.

Comment: I checked and I have installed it into the correct environment: `(QB) Karthiks-MacBook-Pro:QuikBikes karthikpullela$ pip3 list
    DEPRECATION: The default format will switch to columns in the future. You can use --format=(legacy|columns) (or define a format=(legacy|columns) in your pip.conf under the [list] section) to disable this warning.
    configparser (3.5.0)
    Django (2.0)
    django-cors-headers (2.1.0)
    mysqlclient (1.3.12)
    pip (9.0.1)
    pytz (2017.3)
    setuptools (38.2.5)
    wheel (0.30.0)`

Answer (score 0):

Python 3 does not include `ConfigParser`
only has `configparser`

```
>>> import ConfigParser
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
>>> import configparser
```

Try Python 2.7 which still works if we use `import ConfigParser`

Comment: if you were trying to install MySQL-python, then try >>>pip install PyMySQL

Answer (score 0):

Try to install with different package, it has support for python 3.

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

If there is error while installing in virtualenv, do install this first.

```
sudo apt-get -y install python3-dev libmysqlclient-dev
```